# Why 'theme' doesn't change in App.js when I call the hook function from another component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I created a hook for changing MUI theming for React app. It's working fine when i try to change the theme from App.js, but when i call the function "toggleDarkMode" in another component i have the issue: the theme object it's created fine, but the new theme doesn't apply in App.js.

App.js

```
function App( { t } ) {
  const [ theme, toggleDarkMode ] = useDarkMode();
  const themeObj = createMuiTheme(theme);
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={themeObj}>
      <Switch onClick={toggleDarkMode} />
    </ThemeProvider>
    .................
```

custom hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';
import { themeObject } from '../../assets/style/theme'
export const useDarkMode = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(themeObject(false))
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false)
  const userPrefDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
  useEffect(() => {
    doToggleDarkMode();
  }, [darkMode])
  useEffect(() => {
    setDarkMode(userPrefDarkMode)
  }, [userPrefDarkMode])
  const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    setDarkMode(!darkMode)
  }
  const doToggleDarkMode = () => {
    const updatedTheme = {
      ...theme,
      palette: {
        ...theme.palette,
        type: darkMode ? 'dark' : 'light'
      }
    }
    setTheme(updatedTheme)
  }
  return [theme, toggleDarkMode]
}
```

until here it work's fine but when I'm trying to change it from another component it won't work

```
export default function MenuBar(props){
  const [ theme, toggleDarkMode ] = useDarkMode();
  return(
    <Switch onChange={toggleDarkMode}/>
  ..............
```

*MenuBar is not a direct child component to App.js

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the theme returned by `useDarkMode` in `MenuBar`, so I'm not sure what effect you're expecting. If you want to change the theme in `App` then you need to pass its `toggleDarkMode` (e.g. via context) and then use it in `MenuBar`.

Comment: there are no errors, the code it's working fine, but if I toggle theme from MenuBar the App.js doesn't see the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that exist a problem of concept about using hooks in the interface elements that is important to address.

- Create a custom Theme provider it is important to keep all the theme value and change action in the top of the application
- You can use custom hooks with context from the custom Theme provider

I created this sandbox to help with the concepts that you are trying to use.

https://codesandbox.io/s/change-material-ui-theme-xl8nr?file=/src/App.js

The two main files are:

- `CustomThemeProvider.js` -> The Provider
- `useCustomTheme.js` -> The Hook

They are using `createContext` and `useContext` to store the `state` and `setState`.

I used the approach to only save the value `light` or `dark`, but you can change the strategy to save the entire JSON schema for the theme if it is what you need.

Comment: the question was more like 'why the theme const is not changing when I try to toogle it from MenuBar  component', because I saw that if I toggle it from App.js the MenuBar component(children) see the changes but if I toggle it from MenuBar the App.js(parent) doesn't see the change

Comment: @Padi this happens because you are creating a new object `theme` when you call you custom hook `useDarkMode` because it uses `useState` to create a new state when the hook is created. If you don't use `Context` to have one source for this object, you basically created a hook that start from zero every time that you use.

It is not wrong, depending of the case use that you have, but for themes, you must keep the settings in one place that can be used for the whole application.

Comment: yep, 'you basically created a hook that start from zero every time that you use' it was my uncertainty, I made a small ex. to check it :) , anyway I found this example: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/state-management-with-react-hooks-no-redux-or-context-api-8b3035ceecf8 which seems a good way to do it to. Thanks again :)